# CableReady (Rails) Basic case giving mystifying error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cableready

cable_ready 4.5.0
rails 6.1.4.1
ruby 3.0.2p107

This is a simple example from the basic tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5hA79vKE_E) I suspect the error I am getting is because either cable_ready or rails evolved a little and created a tiny incompatibility.

I get this error in the JS console:

[image]

It is triggered when in my controller I ask cable ready to:

```
cable_ready["timeline"].console_log(message: "***** cable ready post created")
```

Which leads to my timeline_channel to:

```
received(data) {
    console.log("******** Received data:", data.operations)
    if (data.cableReady) CableReady.perform(data.operations)
  }
```

My interpretation is perform causes this line in cable_ready.js line 13:

```
  operations.forEach(function (operation) {
    if (!!operation.batch) batches[operation.batch] = batches[operation.batch] ? ++batches[operation.batch] : 1;
  });
```

Is finding something in the received data that it doesn't like.

That's where my trail ends. Can someone see what I am doing wrong, or tell me what other code you'd like me to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: downgrade the version of the cable_ready javascript library.

I previously (maybe a year ago) did [this tutorial](https://dev.to/codefund/build-an-async-progress-bar-with-rails-in-5-steps-2bgp) using CableReady 4.5, Ruby 2.6.5 and Rails 6.0.4 and it worked like a charm back then as well as today.

But today, I tried this tutorial again on a duplicate project--same versions of CR, Ruby, and Rails and now I get java console errors similar to yours.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...operations.forEach...')
perform -- cable_ready.js:13
received -- progress_bar_channel.js:8
```

I looked at the output of `yarn list` and saw that cable_ready was version 5.0.0-pre8 on the bad project and it was 5.0.0-pre1 on the good project. The downgrade could be accomplished with `yarn add cable_ready@^5.0.0-pre1` in the bad project folder and now both projects work.

FYI for other newbies like me trying to understand how CableReady works: [This tutorial](https://longliveruby.com/articles/cable-ready-with-action-cable) gives another example of CableReady, and was also fixed the same way.